# Laptop keeps booting to BIOS after blue screen of death

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bios, hardware-failure

I was loading a game on my computer, when I got a blue screen of death. My computer (laptop) keeps booting to the BIOS. The SSD is listed in the SATA-devices but it does not seem bootable. 
The hard drive is the first one selected in the boot order. I am running dual boot (Windows 10 - Ubuntu) on an MSI GE60 2QD. Is there anything I can do except reinstalling Windows?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Seems the problem is with the windows o.s. boot partition or perhaps the hardware at some point is not compatible with windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution which worked for the problem I had (as described in the question);

1. I booted using a live USB with Partition Wizard (free edition). The boot disk was listed as "unallocated memory" 100% free (which worried me a lot as there was important data on the disk).
2. I used the "partition recovery"-function on the unallocated partition, and it was able to retrieve all the partitions, including my data (yay!).
3. I was able to browse the disk using the "partition explorer", which gave me hope as I was able to see all my folders and files (I was uncertain whether they were corrupted though).
4. Next, I booted using a live USB containing Linux Ubuntu, so I had an OS to access my files and copy them to an external HDD.
5. After manually mounting the drive, I was able to access them and copy them to an external HDD. The files are not corrupted and 100%. It seems the bootmanager crashed and got corrupted at a certain moment. I was not able to restore this with the Windows Restore features.
6. I ended up installing a fresh copy of Windows 10 after backing up my essential files (using Ubuntu as described in the previous step).

I ended up wasting what seemed like endless hours of work, but I guess it was worth it in the end as I was able to recuperate my most valuable files.